# java split sound by silent area

Tags: java, audio

i have a long .wav audio file which contain important sound parts between 2 sound parts there is a empty area .empty mean the time sounds are not recorded .this image shows my clip

[image]

what i want is split this big clip in to small clips by silent area ..this is shown in following image .

[image]

so i want to split `m1.wav` `m2.wav` ,m3.wav and so on ....

can someone show the direction to achieve this ..i don't want codes ..all i need is advice what is the steps to do this

Answer (score 5):

First detect silence (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/5800854/1737819) and then cut the file (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/20228403/1737819) into smaller parts using silence as boundary.

Comment: Is this still the recommended way? Maybe by now there are some good tools libraries for this kind of problem. I am thinking about using a java-ffmpeg-wrapper

Comment: I described how I would approach it.